# How to install nvidia-modprobe

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I am having problems installing `nvidia-modprobe` in a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. Please help with directions as I have no idea how to do this.

I cant even see where the download link is on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-modprobe

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to manually download anything, since that package is available in the Ubuntu software repositories. (In general, it's preferable to install packages from the repositories instead of manually downloading and installing them separately, unless you have a compelling reason to do it the second way.)

---

#### Instructions:

First open a terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Now we'll make sure the "multiverse" repository is enabled. Type the following into the terminal window:

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
```

And refresh the system's package lists from the Ubuntu servers by typing:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now you should be all set to install the "nvidia-modprobe" package, which can be accomplished by typing:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-modprobe
```

**Note**: If you are prompted for a sudo password, type your own user password for Ubuntu.

Please let me know if this was helpful or if you ran into any problems.

Comment: This did install it (at least I think) but it didn't solve the issue that I thought it would. I have Matlab installed and trying to get it to work with my GPU. Running gpuDevice which is to ensure that it can use GPU I get

Error using gpuDevice (line 26)
There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be sure that you have a
supported GPU and that the latest driver is installed.

Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'libcuda.so.1'. The
    error was:
    libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I did follow https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads instructions after turning off X. At least I think I turned it off.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to solve that issue. You might consider contacting Matlab support. In the future it would be helpful to include that type of information in your original question.