# nvidia gtx 1050 and ubuntu 16.04: nvidia-modprobe error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LDS on a new notebook (ASUS with nvidia GTX 1050).

Question:

- How can I solve this error when running "nvidia-modprobe"?

  - Error:

    - modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic

These are ALL the steps I've done from the installation of Ubuntu 16.04:

- "OS updates" from “Ubuntu Software”
- Installed Nvidia drivers

  - Terminal mode con Control - Alt - F1
  - sudo service lightdm stop
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install nvidia-381

    - Error?: UEFI Secure Boot in not compatible withe the use of three-party drivers
- Deactivated the Secure Boot
- sudo service lightdm restart
- GUI mode with Control - Alt - F7
- Docker
- Java 1.8

  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
- Docker for nvidia (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)

  - Error: Job for nvidia-docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See systemctl status nvidia-docker.service and journalctl -xe for details
  - nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
  - Error: nvidia-docker | 2017/07/16 23:13:23 Error: Could not load UVM kernel module. Is nvidia-modprobe installed?
- install nvidia-modprobe ([How to install nvidia-modprobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841824/how-to-install-nvidia-modprobe))

  - sudo apt-add-repository multiverse (it was already active)
  - sudo apt update
  - sudo apt install nvidia-modprobe
- nvidia-modprobe

  - Error:

    - modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic

Comment: it doesn't look like you built a nvidia kernel module.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to. I thought this was the command: "sudo apt-get install nvidia-381". Can you share also the instruction to do that? Or share a link with instructions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem disabling the Secure Boot during Linux installation.

With it enable Linux does not permit to install SW from uncertified providers or SW an with new drivers if the certification procedure has not yet been done, you can't install it and play with it.

The inatallation procedure of Linux Ubuntu 16.04 guides you in deactivating Secure Boot.

After that everything worked fine.