# System is crashing every day with bizz sound and colorful distroted screen. How to solve this Nvidia issue? I am using graphic-driver ppa

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Problem 1: The folder /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced gets deleted every time when I change driver from nvidia to intel or intel to nvidia. Every time I have to fire command

sudo touch /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced && chmod 777 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced

Problem 2: nvidian driver never load on kernel during bootup due to some missing key.

Problem 3: Some error like:-

nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 245

[image]

Comment: The crash is occurs again even I fix  the issue. Please suggest a permanent fix.

Comment: Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema I have installed ubuntu Legacy mode and my UEFI is  already off.

Comment: No, `secure boot` needs to be disabled. Are you dual-booting with Windows? Edit your question to include the terminal output of `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`.

Comment: @heynnema I have this laptop only for ubuntu. UEFI bios setting which is also known as secure boot is already disabled.

Comment: aravind@aravind-aspire-e5-575g:~$ dkms status and dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii
: I do not know how to handle dpkg.
Error!  Unknown option: -l

Comment: that's `dpkg` with a lower case -L. And please copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments, please. Two separate commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65589/discussion-between-aravind-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema Sir the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and get back to you all if it works for my problem 1.

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-384/bin/nvidia-persistenced /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced

Comment: Hello friends,  I will like to tell you all that by making symbolic link of nvidia-presistanced to the /usr/bin/  have solved more then 90% of the problem in Nvidia Graphic card.

Comment: Please don't create nvidia-persistenced in your /usr/bin via touch command.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem Number 2 and 3 are that I have installed modprobe. cuda is installed via old ubuntu software center.

I have also fired " sudo modprobe -m "

[How to install nvidia-modprobe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841824/how-to-install-nvidia-modprobe)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/nvidia-modprobe.1.html

Now my driver is getting loaded in the Kernel.

Now I am able to use it without much problem.